# hover doesn't apply background to li css

Tags: html, css

What's wrong with my :hover below? I dosen't seem to have effect. Tried overflow hidden but it doesn't appear any effect.

```
.tabs-nav li:hover {

}
```

demo https://jsfiddle.net/tpd83jxx/

Comment: Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tpd83jxx/14/

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply the :hover effect in a:hover because you have already applied background-color to a element. Try and add this code.

```
.tabs-nav a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Either do this, or remove the background colour from the anchor tag, but nonetheless, this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with the `css` ,Here you applied `background` for `a` tag.

So change the hover to `a`

```
.tabs-nav li:hover a {
    color: white;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me

```
.tabs-nav li :hover {
  color: white;
  background: red;
}
```

If I am not wrong Space is added to apply hover to the child of li. In this case for anchor tag

Comment: why there's a need of space?

Comment: There is no need for that.

Comment: To apply hover for the child element.